# Memory management of massive parallel ODE solver with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have been solving the Lotka-Volterra equations for a range of test parameters.

However, I am now facing an issue. As I increase the number of parameters my `pickle` file is getting very big. Which means that I can run out of memory when increasing the number of parameters.

How can I manage the script to dump the `result` variable to a file when it reaches e.g., half my ram-size? And when it reaches again half the size, append it to the existing file.

Also in case the `except` block is activated is it possible not to return anything to the `result`variable? That way it would not be necesary to filter a possible hugh `result`variable.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mtp
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

start = time.time()
def derivative(X, t, alpha, beta, delta, gamma):
    x, y = X
    dotx = x * (alpha - beta * y)
    doty = y * (-delta + gamma * x)
    return np.array([dotx, doty])

delta = 1.
gamma = 1.
x0 = 4.
y0 = 2.

Nt = 1000
tmax = 30.
t = np.linspace(0.,tmax, Nt)
X0 = [x0, y0]

betas = np.arange(0.9, 1.4, 0.0005)
alphas = np.arange(0.9, 1.4, 0.0005)

paramlist = list(itertools.product(alphas, betas))

columns = {"time": t}

def function(params):
    alpha, beta = params

    try:
        res = integrate.odeint(derivative, X0, t, args = (alpha, beta, delta, gamma), atol=1e-9, rtol=1e-9)
        x, y = res.T
    except SystemError:
        # fallback values
        x = -1
        y = -1
        print(f"I have an error for alpha: {alpha}, beta: {beta}")

    return {str(alpha)+'+'+ str(beta)+'_x': x,
            str(alpha)+'+'+ str(beta)+'_y': y}
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nProcess = 8
    
    with mtp.Pool(processes= nProcess) as pool:
            results = list( tqdm( pool.imap(function, paramlist), total=len(paramlist)))
    
    for res in results:
        for k, v in res.items():
            columns[k] = v
            
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
    df.to_pickle("test.pickle")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at this. Most of the code in contained in the functions `write_to_file()` and `buffer_iter_to_file()`.

It does the following:

1. It reads from the imap, and appends that to a list.
2. Once the number of elements in that list exceeds N elements, it writes that to a file. It keeps track of all of the files with data.
3. Once done, it reads in all of those files.
4. All of those files are combined into one dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mtp
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
import tempfile
import pickle
import os

start = time.time()
def derivative(X, t, alpha, beta, delta, gamma):
    x, y = X
    dotx = x * (alpha - beta * y)
    doty = y * (-delta + gamma * x)
    return np.array([dotx, doty])

delta = 1.
gamma = 1.
x0 = 4.
y0 = 2.

Nt = 1000
tmax = 30.
t = np.linspace(0.,tmax, Nt)
X0 = [x0, y0]

betas = np.arange(0.9, 1.4, 0.0005)
alphas = np.arange(0.9, 1.4, 0.005)

paramlist = list(itertools.product(alphas, betas))

columns = {"time": t}

def function(params):
    alpha, beta = params

    try:
        res = integrate.odeint(derivative, X0, t, args = (alpha, beta, delta, gamma), atol=1e-9, rtol=1e-9)
        x, y = res.T
    except SystemError:
        # fallback values
        x = -1
        y = -1
        print(f"I have an error for alpha: {alpha}, beta: {beta}")

    return {str(alpha)+'+'+ str(beta)+'_x': x,
            str(alpha)+'+'+ str(beta)+'_y': y}


def write_to_file(results):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
        delete=False,
        dir='./tmp',
        prefix='ode_',
        suffix='.pickle'
    ) as handle:
        # convert to dict
        sub_df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for result in results for k, v in result.items()})
        pickle.dump(sub_df, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        return handle.name


def buffer_iter_to_file(iterator, chunksize):
    results = []
    files = []
    # Read from iterator
    for result in iterator:
        results.append(result)
        # If results list gets too big, write it to disk
        if len(results) >= chunksize:
            filename = write_to_file(results)
            results = []
            files.append(filename)

    # Add any remaining results to pickle file
    if len(results) > 0:
        filename = write_to_file(results)
        results = []
        files.append(filename)

    # Define generator in wrapped function so preceding code is executed immediately
    def _generator():
        # Load pickle files and yield them
        for filename in files:
            with open(filename, 'rb') as handle:
                yield pickle.load(handle)
            # Delete file once done
            os.remove(filename)
    return _generator()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nProcess = 4
    results = []
    with mtp.Pool(processes= nProcess) as pool:
        # Run in parallel
        iterable = pool.imap(function, paramlist)
        # Show a progress meter
        iterable = tqdm(iterable, total=len(paramlist))
        # Buffer results to file
        results = buffer_iter_to_file(iterable, 10000)

    # Load results from file and concatenate them into one dataframe
    df = pd.concat(results, axis=1)
    df.to_pickle("test.pickle")
```

However, this solution falls short in some ways. In the step where it is running `df = pd.concat(results, axis=1)`, it needs to have every prior result in memory in order to produce the combined DataFrame. That takes, at minimum, 1000 * 2 * number of alphas * number of betas * 8 bytes.

For large numbers of parameters, that's not going to work. I managed to knock some memory usage off of this by having fewer copies of data in memory at once, but fundamentally, Pandas requires the ability to have the entire DataFrame in memory at once. However, advice about how to use Pandas on large datasets can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html).

Comment: Hi Mr. ODell! Thanks for all the help! A question: I can have multiple `with mtp.Pool(processes= nProcess) as pool:` statements to run multiple blocks in parallel, right? 
Would it be effective if I had ran the code in chunks of 10000 or until end of `paramlist` wrote the first time to file and every consequent time, appended the results to the end of the file?

Comment: @R.Smith You can, but if you want to run multiple `map`s in parallel, it won't be any faster than running one `map` after another. E.g. if you have 8 CPU cores, and they are all occupied doing one `map`, then doing another does not make the program any faster - the `map`s have to share the CPU cores.

Comment: Would `dask` be a good option in here?

Comment: No idea. Never used it.